# How to handle null and text values when finding average in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, casting, postgresql-14

I have a table that looks like below (only a sample provided)

```
            date            |  memory   |      cpu       
----------------------------+-----------+----------------
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.102194 |        37 | -1
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.106863 |        37 | -1
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.110286 |        37 | -1
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.114442 |        37 | -1
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.118419 |        37 | -1
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.121983 | 31.519346 | 7.0, 7.0, 7.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.125608 | 31.519346 | 7.0, 7.0, 7.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.12989  | 31.519346 | 7.0, 7.0, 7.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.134142 | 31.519346 | 7.0, 7.0, 7.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.137253 | 31.519346 | 7.0, 7.0, 7.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.143885 | 31.542543 | 24.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.148455 | 31.542543 | 24.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.151906 | 30.906942 | 11.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.155327 | 35.317715 | 12.0, 6.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.161415 | 35.317715 | 12.0, 6.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.16701  | 35.317715 | 12.0, 6.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.170698 | 35.317715 | 12.0, 6.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.174565 | 17.155323 | 1.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.177928 | 17.155323 | 1.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.181603 | 17.155323 | 1.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.185589 | 32.224056 | 14.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.188934 | 32.224056 | 14.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.193468 |  7.368925 | 1.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.198035 |  7.368925 | 1.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.201166 | 31.726305 | 27.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.205302 |        -1 | 4.0, 3.0, 3.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.208874 |        -1 | 4.0, 3.0, 3.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.212153 |        -1 | 4.0, 3.0, 3.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.215573 |  18.09042 | 1.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.219527 |   41.8536 | 11.0, 1.0, 1.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.222841 |   41.8536 | 11.0, 1.0, 1.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.226778 | 27.492594 | 23.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.230332 |  8.857008 | 2.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.234988 |  8.857008 | 2.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.238463 |  8.857008 | 2.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.242749 | 20.523735 | 4.0, 2.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.246553 | 20.523735 | 4.0, 2.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.250473 | 20.523735 | 4.0, 2.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.254418 | 20.523735 | 4.0, 2.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.25883  | 20.523735 | 4.0, 2.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.26222  | 29.214113 | 13.0
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.265766 | 29.214113 | 13.0
```

As you can see this table stores `cpu` and `memory` readings along with `date`. The `cpu` columns contains comma separated values. So I split it out into individual columns like so

**SQL**

```
SELECT
  date,
  memory,
  split_part(cpu, ',', 1) AS cpu1,
  split_part(cpu, ',', 2) AS cpu2,
  split_part(cpu, ',', 3) AS cpu3,
  split_part(cpu, ',', 4) AS cpu4
FROM
  webhook_devicedata
where
  date between '2022-10-06 02:03:00'
  and '2022-10-06 02:04:00'
order by
  date;
```

**SQL Output**

```
            date            |  memory   | cpu1 | cpu2 | cpu3 | cpu4 
----------------------------+-----------+------+------+------+------
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.102194 |        37 | -1   |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.106863 |        37 | -1   |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.110286 |        37 | -1   |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.114442 |        37 | -1   |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.118419 |        37 | -1   |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.121983 | 31.519346 | 7.0  |  7.0 |  7.0 | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.125608 | 31.519346 | 7.0  |  7.0 |  7.0 | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.12989  | 31.519346 | 7.0  |  7.0 |  7.0 | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.134142 | 31.519346 | 7.0  |  7.0 |  7.0 | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.137253 | 31.519346 | 7.0  |  7.0 |  7.0 | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.143885 | 31.542543 | 24.0 |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.148455 | 31.542543 | 24.0 |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.151906 | 30.906942 | 11.0 |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.155327 | 35.317715 | 12.0 |  6.0 |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.161415 | 35.317715 | 12.0 |  6.0 |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.16701  | 35.317715 | 12.0 |  6.0 |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.170698 | 35.317715 | 12.0 |  6.0 |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.174565 | 17.155323 | 1.0  |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.177928 | 17.155323 | 1.0  |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.181603 | 17.155323 | 1.0  |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.185589 | 32.224056 | 14.0 |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.188934 | 32.224056 | 14.0 |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.193468 |  7.368925 | 1.0  |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.198035 |  7.368925 | 1.0  |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.201166 | 31.726305 | 27.0 |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.205302 |        -1 | 4.0  |  3.0 |  3.0 | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.208874 |        -1 | 4.0  |  3.0 |  3.0 | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.212153 |        -1 | 4.0  |  3.0 |  3.0 | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.215573 |  18.09042 | 1.0  |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.219527 |   41.8536 | 11.0 |  1.0 |  1.0 | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.222841 |   41.8536 | 11.0 |  1.0 |  1.0 | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.226778 | 27.492594 | 23.0 |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.230332 |  8.857008 | 2.0  |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.234988 |  8.857008 | 2.0  |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.238463 |  8.857008 | 2.0  |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.242749 | 20.523735 | 4.0  |  2.0 |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.246553 | 20.523735 | 4.0  |  2.0 |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.250473 | 20.523735 | 4.0  |  2.0 |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.254418 | 20.523735 | 4.0  |  2.0 |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.25883  | 20.523735 | 4.0  |  2.0 |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.26222  | 29.214113 | 13.0 |      |      | 
 2022-10-06 02:03:30.265766 | 29.214113 | 13.0 |      |      |
```

Now I want to group by `date` and get average of `memory` and individual `cpu` columns on an hourly basis. If you look carefully, the column `cpu1` has all the values. So running the query below works

**SQL**

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('hour', date) as hourly,
  avg(COALESCE(split_part(cpu, ',', 1) :: text) :: float) AS cpu1
FROM
  webhook_devicedata
where
  date between '2022-10-06 02:03:00'
  and '2022-10-06 02:04:00'
group by
  hourly;
```

I get the result

```
       hourly        |       cpu1        
---------------------+-------------------
 2022-10-06 02:00:00 | 7.309523809523809
```

But as soon as I start involving other `cpu` columns, I get an error

**SQL**

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('hour', date) as hourly,
  avg(COALESCE(split_part(cpu, ',', 1) :: text) :: float) AS cpu1,
  avg(COALESCE(split_part(cpu, ',', 2) :: text) :: float) AS cpu2
FROM
  webhook_devicedata
where
  date between '2022-10-06 02:03:00'
  and '2022-10-06 02:04:00'
group by
  hourly;
```

**Error**

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
CONTEXT:  parallel worker
```

I even tried to get rid of `null` and empty strings by writing the query like below

**SQL**

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('hour', sub2.date) as hourly,
  avg(sub2.cpu1) as avg_cpu1,
  avg(sub2.cpu2) as avg_cpu2
from
  (
    select
      date,
      memory,
      split_part(cpu, ',', 1) :: text as cpu1,
      split_part(cpu, ',', 2) :: text as cpu2
    FROM
      (
        select
          date,
          memory,
          cpu
        from
          webhook_devicedata
        where
          date between '2022-10-06 02:03:00'
          and '2022-10-06 02:04:00'
          and cpu != ''
          and cpu is not null
      ) as sub
  ) as sub2
group by
  hourly;
```

But I get the below error

**Error**

```
ERROR:  function avg(text) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT date_trunc('hour', sub2.date) as hourly, avg(sub2.cpu...
                                                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the average of all the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check values using case, example:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('hour', date) as hourly,
  avg(case when split_part(cpu, ',', 1) = '' then 0 else split_part(cpu, ',', 1):: float end) AS cpu1,
  avg(case when split_part(cpu, ',', 2) = '' then 0 else split_part(cpu, ',', 2):: float end) AS cpu2
FROM
  webhook_devicedata
where
  date between '2022-10-06 02:03:00'
  and '2022-10-06 02:04:00'
group by
  hourly;
```